# $7x+5y=12$, so why does its solution will be of the format $(1+5n,1-7n)$

Tags: linear-diophantine-equations, coprime

**Question**

> Consider all ordered pairs of integers $(x,y)$ such that $$\frac{5}{x}+\frac{7}{y} = \frac{12}{xy}.$$
> The smallest positive integer value of $x$ in these ordered pairs is 1, since $x=y=1$ satisfies the equation. What is the second smallest positive integer value of $x$ in these ordered pairs?

If I rearrange the equation I get $7x+5y=12$. I have been told that **$5$ and $7$ are relatively coprime therefore solution will be of the format $(1+5n,1-7n)$**

The bold Part in above argument is what I don't understand.

Comment: Only integer values of $x$ make both $5x$ and $7x$ be integers

Comment: **Dupe** of [Find all integer solutions to $7595x + 1023y=124$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182464/find-all-integer-solutions-to-7595x-1023y-124).  In particular see the **general** solution method in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182469/242)

Comment: Here's [another dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3488324/242), and see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3818229/242) for analogs for differential and difefrence equations (recurrences).

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks for your reply I found it helpful, can you guide me how do you remember such results.

Comment: The idea I describe in elementary langauge about the form of the general solution is a basic result of linear algebra / modules (which will be clarified when rephrased more structurally in terms of images and kernels and the associated isomorphism theorem).  Thanks for the typo correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If a prime $p$ divides $ab$ then either $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

Now use it in the relation $7(x-1)=5(1-y)$.

Comment: can you guide me how develop thinking like that, any book to read or refer me to any resource.

Comment: I think it will be n only as if fix one variable other will also be fixed as answer is integer.

Comment: Yes n will be fixed

Comment: Solving Mathematical Problems by Terence Tao is a great book to develop mathematical thinking